# Stack Exchange iOS 1.6.6 app crashes Settings app when exiting Notices

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to Reproduce:

On an iPhone, go to the Settings app → stack exchange → *Notices* → (pick any one) → back to *Notices*

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone XS Max 64 GB (iPhone11,6)
- OS Version: Version 13.1.3 (Build 17A878)

Comment: Is it really spelled "stack exchange" in the app?

Comment: I can add a screenshot if you’d like

Comment: The app hasnt been maintained, nor will be, for a while. Don't expect any fixes. You can use the responsive design on a mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually an iOS bug, not a bug with the Stack Exchange app.

The crash was fixed in iOS 13.2.